# org.w3c.dom: get element's height and width?

Tags: java, dom, element

I have loaded a `org.w3c.dom` dom document on to the component.

I want to get each element to highlight.

For example, on mouseover, I would get the element from this point and then get the dimension of this element so that I can create a Jframe on top of this element with a colored border.

Is it possible to get an element's height and width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM API doesn't really handle HTML or rendering, it's a pure representation of the elements of an XML element.

Those elements have no inherent size (or color, or z-index, ...).

If you want that information, you'd need to have some component that actually renders your document (or at least produces a layout that could be rendered).

Is there such a component in your application? Is your code running as an Applet in a browser?

Comment: +1 - I think he might be confusing the W3C DOM API with the Javascript HtmlDocument / HtmlElement classes.  (There is a distinction between them even in Javascript ...)

Comment: yes to first question. no to second. I think the loaded dom is than displayed on a component and I can access it.

Comment: @Kim: in that case you will have to ask the component doing the displaying for that information.